# Nodejs Post API is not hitting with Postman or application?

Tags: node.js, api, post

I am trying to test a **POST API in Postman**, it is not giving any response only giving this information - `Error: socket hang up`, I have checked the node console it only has message -

API - `http://localhost:3000/articles`

```
Server started listening on port 3000
connected to MongoDB
```

I tried with - `nodemon --inspect index.js` I am clueless how will I debug my code to know where is the issue exactly.

**index.js**

```
var articleRouter = require("./article-main/article-route");

//connection MongoDB using Mongoose.
mongoose.set("debug", (query) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(query));
});

mongoose.Promise = Promise;

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    readPreference: "secondaryPreferred",
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("connected to MongoDB");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("error connecting to MongoDB", err);
  }); 

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});

//   const server = https.createServer(options, app);
const server = https.createServer(app);
server.timeout = 600000;
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server started listening on port ${PORT}`);
});

app.use("/articles", articleRouter);

module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

**article-controller.js**

```
const articlesModule = require("./article-model");
const axios = require("axios");

var articlepost = async (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send({ message: "Article posted successfully" });
};

module.exports = {
  articlepost: articlepost,
};
```

**article-routes**

```
var express = require("express");
var articleMainController = require("../article-main/article-controller");
var articleRouter = express.Router();

articleRouter.route("/articles").post(articleMainController.articlepost);

module.exports = articleRouter;
```